# How to create movie screenshot by ffmpeg in an amazon S3 path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I tried to create using ffmpeg a video screenshot from a remote video url in heroku console. Below is how I generated a movie instance and can see also an empty ready to be written file at S3. But the last line movie.screenshot is not working and generates this error:

```
FFMPEG::Error: Failed encoding.Errors: no output file created
```

Here is the code

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-west-1')
bucket = s3.bucket("ruby-sample-kb-#{SecureRandom.uuid}")
bucket.create
object = bucket.object('ex-vid-test-kb.jpg')
object.put(acl: "public-read-write")
path = object.public_url
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/seppoav/o/3606137_51447286560__56BAF29C-05CB-4223-BAE6-655DF2236321.MOV?generation=1492780072394755&alt=media")
movie.screenshot(path, :seek_time => 2)
```

I also tried the following line just if it should be written via put. What am I missing here?

```
object.put(acl: "public-read", body: movie.screenshot(path, :seek_time => 2))
```

Comment: movie.valid? is true which shows that the movie is created well. The path is also fine. So the googleapis is just to read the movie file and transcode it to form the movie object.

Comment: I misread this, apologies, and thought you were attempting to upload. Will delete comment shortly. Presumably you have ffmpeg executable/libraries installed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up convincing myself that ffmpeg movie.screenshot won't work for remote url path. So I had to figure out a solution where I can create tempfile in heroku system although the tempfiles stay per dyno.

```
file = Tempfile.new [prefix, suffix], "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/video_screenshots"
movie.screenshot(file.path)
```

This worked Ok.